# Finding partial text in range

Tags: excel

I need to find some partial text in a range (random / range cell)
Here's my capture

[image]

Yellow : What I need to find (Parameter to find)
Blue : What I need to get

I already combination try "Trim, Search, Find", but it's still failed since it was a range and have a random cell to found.

Need your help and advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first try:

```
=Clean(Trim(MID(A1,FIND("uptime is",A1)+10,LEN(A1)-FIND("uptime is",A1)+10)))
```

For the second try:

```
=Clean(Trim(MID(A6,FIND("System image file",A6)+21,LEN(A6)-FIND("System image file",A6)+21)))
```

Comment: It might be better to use SEARCH instead of FIND to avoid the case-sensitivity.

Comment: @Imran Malek your statement is absolutely right but in this case i use Find function to narrow down the possibility of errors because i believe that the data scraped from internet which may cause farther issues.that is why i use Clean & Trim functions.

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions assume you know what cell to look in.  Based on your question, it sounds like you just want to search the column for what you're looking for.  Assuming the column with all of the text lines is column A, this should work for you.

Formula for system uptime:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*"&"uptime is"&"*",A:A,0)),"uptime is",REPT(" ",9999)),9999))
```

Formula for System image file:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*"&"System image file is"&"*",A:A,0)),"System image file is",REPT(" ",9999)),9999))
```

Note that you could replace the strings with a cell reference.  For example, put `uptime is` in cell Y1 and `System image file is` in cell Y2, and then you could use this formula in cell Z1 and copy down:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*"&Y1&"*",A:A,0)),Y1,REPT(" ",9999)),9999))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function with regex

**UDF in sheet:**

[image]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetStringAfter(rng As Range, ByVal findString As String) As Variant
    Dim pattern As String, re As Object

    If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        GetStringAfter = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If

    pattern = "(.*" & findString & ")(.*)"

    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .pattern = pattern
        If .test(rng.Text) Then
            GetStringAfter = Trim$(.Replace(rng.Text, "$2"))
        Else
            GetStringAfter = "Not found"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

---

**Regex:**

[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/hQlnYR/1)

The first group is everything upto and including the search phrase. The second is everything after. If search string found only the bit in the second group is returned.

```
(.*uptime is)(.*)
/
gm
```

**1st Capturing Group (.*uptime is)**

`.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)

`*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`uptime is` matches the characters `uptime is` literally (case sensitive)

**2nd Capturing Group (.*)**

`.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)

`*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)